# iOS universal links not opening

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I know there are a dozen of questions exactly like this one on here, and I've checked every possible answer, yet I'm still in the dark.

I've configured the website and iOS app exactly as described in the documentation and even after following countless advice from other questions on here, I still can't seem to get universal links to work.

**This is my `apple-app-site-association` file**

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "[TEAM_ID].[BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER]",
        "paths": [
          "/auth-callback/"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, my only path I need to support is `/auth-callback` because I need the browser to redirect back to the app after I complete authentication in Safari.

On client side, I've added `Associated Domains` capability and a domain `applinks:https://myapp-portal.azurewebsites.net`

Now that the association file is hosted on the website, I've tried to test if it works by opening URL `https://myapp-portal.azurewebsites.net/auth-callback/` from my notes app, but it still won't redirect to my app.

I also used [this universal link validator](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com) and here's the result.

[image]

I'm pretty sure my content-type is set correctly, but could this still be the actual issue?

Comment: AFAICT the warning about `Content-Type` is no longer relevant (those files used to be signed, but that restriction was lifted when https was made mandatory). You're sure about team id and bundle identifier being correct?

Comment: @Gereon yes, definitely sure about those 2 things.